# Merge two immutable maps

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am using Redux and Immutable.js and I am trying to filter the flashcard sequence and also set flashcards to hidden. Then return that state using redux. My data model looks like this:

```
"flashcardSequence": ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
  "flashcards": {
    "id1": {
      "cgi": "id1",
      "creatorGuid": "student1",
      "authoringType": "STUDENT",
      "sequence": 0,
      "hidden": false,
      "suppressed": false,
      "aspects": {
        "123": {
          "id": "123",
          "role": "Date",
          "value": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "value": "1776"
            }
          ],
          "label": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "value": "Date"
            }
          ]
        },
```

In my flashcard reducer, my code is this:

```
 case types.HIDE_FLASHCARD: {
      const index = state
        .get('decks')
        .findIndex(i => i.get('deckCgi') === action.deckCgi);

      const card = state
        .getIn(['decks', index, 'flashcards'])
        .find(i => i.get('cgi') === action.cardId);

      const filteredSequence = state
        .getIn(['decks', index, 'flashcardSequence'])
        .filter(flashcardId => flashcardId !== action.cardId);

      // return state.setIn(
      //   ['decks', index, 'flashcardSequence'],
      //   filteredSequence
      // );

      let filteredSequenceState = state.setIn(
        ['decks', index, 'flashcardSequence'],
        filteredSequence
      );

      let hiddenCardState = state.setIn(
        ['decks', index, 'flashcards', action.cardId],
        card.set('hidden', true)
      );
      //I would like to combine both states into one single object without writing over any data.
      return filteredSequence + filteredSequenceState;
    }
```

What I am struggling with is how do I return both states to my application? Returning the object independently of each other works perfectly but I am unable to merge them.  I have tried to merge them with the methods provided to me to no avail. I would like to return filteredSequence and hiddenCardState.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: in order to get good quick and currect answer try to simplify your code as posible, remove parts that dosent have to be on the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
const filteredSequenceState = state.setIn(
        ['decks', index, 'flashcardSequence'],
        filteredSequence
);

const hiddenCardState = filteredSequenceState.setIn(
        ['decks', index, 'flashcards', action.cardId],
        card.set('hidden', true)
);

return filteredSequenceState;
```

will do what you want?
Side note: better to use `const` instead of `let` if you do not change your variables.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. I also appreciate the comment about naming my variables. Still learning ES6. Thanks.